# Items.restrict method to look for items that are sent today

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a code to download weekly assignments (attachments) and save it to a folder.

I got a code which goes through every item and downloads all the attachments but it goes from latest to earliest date. I need the latest one as the earlier attachments will overwrite the later ones.

I added a restrict method to look for items that are sent today but it still goes through the whole inbox.

```
Sub downloadAttachment()

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim myItems As Items
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sFilter As String


'Setting variable for inbox.
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
**sFilter = "[ReceivedTime]>=""&Date()12:00am&"""
Set myItems = Inbox.Items.Restrict(sFilter)**

i = 0

'Error handling.
On Error GoTo downloadattachment_err

'if no attachments, msgbox displays.
If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
            "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Goes through each item in inbox for attachments.
For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
    If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "txt" Then
        FileName = "C:\losscontroldbases\pendingworkdownload\" & Atmt.FileName
        Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next Atmt
Next Item

'If attachments found, the displays message.
If i > 0 Then
    MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
    & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\losscontroldbases\pendingworkdownload." _
    & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day!"

Else
    MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail."
End If

'Clearing memory.
downloadattachment_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub

'Error handling code.
downloadattachment_err:
    MsgBox " An unexpected error has occured."

End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed it already. Thank you for asking!

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer, so we know its solved

Answer (score 3):

Your code references "date" string as a literal value. Use something like

```
Filter = "[ReceivedTime]>= '" & CStr(Date()) & " 12:00am' "
```

Comment: Hello, how would I make the Filter set to todays current date?

Comment: You woudl need to have two parts: `>=` midnight today and `<` then tomorrow midnight

Comment: Ok thank you, there’s no datetime.today() function? I am still researching.

Comment: No. DateTime in COM is an 8 byte float (double) that stores both date and time. What you are asking is a range (midnight to midnight) - you cannot use `=` with DateTime fields, it must always be a range.